# Set image dimension for WP_Customize_Image_Control images

Tags: images, theme-customizer, cropping

In the customize page for the current theme the Current Header's Choose Image dialog shows - a "select and crop" option
[image: Select and Crop option in chose Image dialog of Current Header]

But the custom WP_Customize_Image_Control shows only "Choose Image". [image: Select Image dialog generated by WP_Customize_Image_Control]

Is there a way to define image size/dimension for the images uploaded using WP_Customize_Image_Control, may be by using [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) . And will this trigger the WP_Customize_Image_Control uploader to show a "Select and Crop" option ?

ps: There is a request for such a feature as per [this ticket.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29211)

Comment: I think there is no way. The only thing you can do for now is recommend a image size for the header to the users of the theme. But I can not confirm this at 100%.

Comment: Can't a filter be used somehow to make this work ? Ofcourse, informing the user is the last option.

Answer (score -2):

I managed that with css. This is how i did it:

1. On your header.php file add a class to your image tag like this:

   ```
   img class="logo" src="" alt=""
   ```
2. Then, on your style.css add the logo class:

   ```
   .logo { max-width: 200px; }
   ```

If needs any change afterwards just go to the **Editor** and change the value directly in the **style.css** file.

Comment: Hi Carlos, welcome to WPSE. Please feel free to [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for your answer, however this won't affect the size of the crop control in the media library, as the questioner has asked.

Comment: Thanks for responding Carlos but I needed it to work through WordPress.